# What are a stone on a cone on a bone and a stone on a bone?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

The following cryptic message is supposed to tell me the secret code I have to give the guard that he lets me in.

> A bone and a bone are a cone on a bone.
>
> A bone on a cone is the opposite of a cone on a bone.
>
> The opposite of a stone is a stone.
>
> A stone on a bone and the opposite of a cone on a bone are a bone.
>
> A stone on a bone for each bone on a cone is a stone on a bone on a cone.
>
> A cone and a bone on a cone are the opposite of a stone on a bone.
>
> A cone for each stone on a bone is a stone on a cone.
>
> A cone on a bone for each cone on a bone is a bone on a bone.
>
> What are a stone on a cone on a bone and a stone on a bone?

Apparently I need to tell the guard a specific stack of objects. But what is it?

Here's a hint I've found in a fortune cookie:

> Remember that every thing has value.

A manager gave me this valuable hint:

> Your power depends on your position.

The following insight from a self-help book might also be helpful:

> We also need the negative things in life.

I've also got a hint from a TV series fan:

> You really should know the power of three.

Comment: I'm not sure whether to get stoned or a boner now

Comment: Seeing as we're talking about stacks, should "the opposite of A on B" mean, "B on A"?

Comment: @RoadieRich: No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, we have a lot of hints now and I think they're enough.

We are working in

> balanced ternary

and "X on Y on Z" means

> the balanced-ternary number ZYX; that is, X + 3Y + 9Z

where

> a bone is +1, a cone is -1, and a stone is 0.

The other operations are

> "and" = addition, "for each" = multiplication, "opposite" = negation.

Accordingly, a stone on a cone on a bone and a stone on a bone equal

> [0 + 3*(-1) + 9] + [0 + 3] = 9

which we describe as

> a stone on a stone on a bone.

Let's go through the statements we've been given and check them.

A bone and a bone are a cone on a bone.

> 1 + 1 = (-1) + 3*1. 2 on both sides, check.

A bone on a cone is the opposite of a cone on a bone.

> 1 + 3*(-1) = -[-1 + 3*(1)]. -2 on both sides, check.

The opposite of a stone is a stone.

> -0 = 0, check.

A stone on a bone and the opposite of a cone on a bone are a bone.

> 0 + 3*1 - (-1 + 3*1) = 1.

A stone on a bone for each bone on a cone is a stone on a bone on a cone.

> (0 + 3*1) * (1 + 3*-1) = 0 + 3*1 + 9*-1. -6 on both sides, check.

A cone and a bone on a cone are the opposite of a stone on a bone.

> [-1] + [1 + 3*-1] = -[0 + 3*1]. -3 on both sides, check.

A cone for each stone on a bone is a stone on a cone.

> -1 * (0 + 3*1) = (0 + 3*-1). -3 on both sides, check.

A cone on a bone for each cone on a bone is a bone on a bone.

> (-1 + 3*1) * (-1 + 3*1) = (1 + 3*1), or 2*2=4, check.

Comment: You got it! Bone.

Comment: In fairness, by the time I looked at it today the hints were more or less a solution :-). Then again, there's a geometry-ish puzzle still open where the hints are basically a very detailed solution outline and everyone, including me, has been avoiding the work of actually doing it...

Answer (score 3):

This can only be a partial solution, because I don't understand any rule which contains the word "each".
Anyway, Let $s$ = a stone, $c$ = a cone, $b$ = a bone, $1$ = a stack with nothing on it. Say $x+y$ for $x$ and $y$, and $xy$ for $x$ on $y$. Say $x^{-1}$ for the opposite of $x$. Say $xy=1$ or $yx=1$ if it's stated that $x$ is the opposite to $y$. (Actually, seeing as we have two operators, "and" and "on", I am not sure which operator "opposite" refers to.) Then

$$ \begin{matrix}
& b+b & = & cb & [1]\\
& bc & = & (cb)^{-1} & [2]\\
& ss & = & 1 & [3] \\
& sb+(cb)^{-1} & = & b & [4] \\
& c+bc & = & (sb)^{-1} & [6] \\
\Rightarrow & sb & = & b+cb & (4) \\
&&=&b+b+b & (1)\\
& sb+c+bc & = & 1 & (6)\\
\Rightarrow & b+c & = & 1\\
& scb & = & s(b+b) & (1) \\
&& = & sb+sb\\
\Rightarrow & scb+sb & = & sb+sb+sb \\
&& = & b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b
\end{matrix}
$$

At least, that's one interpretation. Of course, I might've been attacking quite the wrong problem.

Comment: You're partly on the right way, but not completely. Interestingly, your first conclusion (the line labelled $(4)$) doesn't seem to follow from the preceding lines (at least I cannot see how), but translates to a correct statement.

Comment: Since we deal with stacks of at least 2 objects probably the opposite of y/x would be x/y. For a stack made of 1 object the extra condition opposite of x = x is given in line 3 since 1/x wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Surely 4 is just what you get by combining "A stone on a bone and the opposite of a cone on a bone are a bone" and "A bone on a cone is the opposite of a cone on a bone", so it's not surprising it's correct.

Comment: In my interpretation of the question I too came up with a system of equations, but I didn't interpret stacks to be multiplication, or opposites to be inverses.

Answer (score -1):

Is it:

> A stone?

Based on:

> stone = 1; bone = 2; cone = 4;

Where:

> 'on' is to divide, 'and' is to add, and 'for each' is to multiply.
> A bone and a bone are a cone on a bone.
> b+b = c/b, thus c=2b.
> A bone on a cone is the opposite of a cone on a bone.
> I assume this to mean, b/c is the opposite of c/b 
> The opposite of a stone is a stone.
> This only holds for 1/1, so s=1 
> A stone on a bone and the opposite of a cone on a bone are a bone.
> Math happened.  B=2 and C=4
> So I skipped ahead and tried my theory so far.
> What are a stone on a cone on a bone and a stone on a bone?
> (1/4)/2 + 1/2 = 1

There might be a valid statement in there, but I doubt it....

Comment: No. And your interpretation already violates the first statement: "a bone and a bone" would be 4, while "a cone on a bone" would be 2.